# Consumer causing memory leak on Wildfly AS

Tags: java, wildfly, producer-consumer, hornetq, wildfly-9

I have a `producer` `consumer` setup using a `Wildfly` AS for `JMS`, the producer uses a `newFixedThreadPool(126)` every 1 minute each thread is pulling data down from a `REST` service and is pushing it onto a `HornetQ`on the `Wildfly` AS.

Then on the consumer side I have a Consumer class that consumes the messges in the `HornetQ` and a simple `Parser` class, for DB insertion, I instantiate an object of type `Parser` in my `onMessage()` and then pass the message to it, the message is in `JSON` and my parser class loops through it getting the values and inserting them into my DB.

Consumer:

```
public void Consume(Consumer asyncReceiver) throws Throwable {

    try {
        /** Get the initial context */
        final Properties props = new Properties();
        /** If debugging in IDE the properties are acceded this way */
        if(debug){
            InputStream f = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("consumer.properties");
            props.load(f);
        }
        /** If running the .jar artifact the properties are acceded this way*/
        else{
            File jarPath = new File(getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
            String propertiesPath = jarPath.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath();
            props.load(new FileInputStream(propertiesPath + File.separator + "consumer.properties"));
        }

        /** These few lines should be removed and setup in the properties file*/
        props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, props.getProperty("INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY"));
        props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, props.getProperty("PROVIDER_URL"));
        props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, props.getProperty("DEFAULT_USERNAME"));
        props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, props.getProperty("DEFAULT_PASSWORD"));
        context = new InitialContext(props);

        /** Lookup the queue object */
        Queue queue = (Queue) context.lookup(props.getProperty("DEFAULT_DESTINATION"));

        /** Lookup the queue connection factory */
        ConnectionFactory connFactory = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup(props.getProperty("DEFAULT_CONNECTION_FACTORY"));

         /** Create a queue connection */
        connection = connFactory.createConnection(props.getProperty("DEFAULT_USERNAME"), props.getProperty("DEFAULT_PASSWORD"));

         /** Create a queue session */
         queueSession = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

         /** Create a queue consumer */
         msgConsumer = queueSession.createConsumer(queue);

         /** Set an asynchronous message listener */
        msgConsumer.setMessageListener(asyncReceiver);

         /** Set an asynchronous exception listener on the connection */
        connection.setExceptionListener(asyncReceiver);

        /** Start connection */
        connection.start();

         /** Wait for messages */
        System.out.println("waiting for messages");
        for (int i = 0; i < 47483647; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.print(".");
        }
        System.out.println();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.severe(e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }finally {
        if (context != null) {
            context.close();
        }
        if (queueSession != null)
        { queueSession.close();
        }
        if(msgConsumer != null){
            msgConsumer.close();
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    TextMessage msg = (TextMessage) message;
    try {
        Parser parser = new Parser();
        parser.parseApplication(msg.getText());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Parser:

```
 public void parseApplication(String NRData) throws Exception {

        DBConnection db = DBConnection.createApplication();
        db.getConnection();
        JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);
        JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(NRData);

        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> fieldsIterator = rootNode.fields();
        while (fieldsIterator.hasNext()) {

            Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> field = fieldsIterator.next();
            String envName = field.getKey();
            JsonNode appValue = field.getValue();
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(appValue.toString());
            String appName = jsonArray.getString(0);
            String appID = jsonArray.getString(1);
            JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(2);

            JSONObject metricsData = json.getJSONObject("metric_data");
            JSONArray metrics = metricsData.getJSONArray("metrics");
            JSONObject array1 = metrics.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONArray timeslices = array1.getJSONArray("timeslices");

            for (int i = 0; i < timeslices.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject array2 = timeslices.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject values = array2.getJSONObject("values");
//                Instant from = array2.getString("from");
                Instant from = TimestampUtils.parseTimestamp(array2.get("from").toString(), null);
                Instant to = TimestampUtils.parseTimestamp(array2.get("to").toString(), null);
                Iterator<String> nameItr = values.keys();
                while (nameItr.hasNext()) {
                    String name = nameItr.next();
                    System.out.println(
                            "\nEnv name: " + envName +
                                    "\nApp name: " + appName +
                                    "\nApp ID: " + appID +
                                    "\nRequest per minute: " + values.getDouble(name) +
                                    "\nFrom: " + from + " To: " + to);

                    ThroughputEntry TP = new ThroughputEntry();
                    TP.setThroughput(values.getDouble(name));
                    TP.setEnvironment(envName);
                    TP.setName(appName);
                    TP.setRetrieved(from);
                    TP.setPeriodEnd(to);

                    db.addHistory(TP);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

DBconnection :

```
public class DBConnection {

private final String table;


/**
 * Set the table name for applications
 */
public static DBConnection createApplication() {
    return new DBConnection("APPLICATIONDATA");
}

public DBConnection(String table) {
    this.table = String.format("NRDATA.%s", table);
}

public Connection getConnection() throws IllegalAccessException,
        InstantiationException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    try {
        Class.forName("COM.ibm.db2os390.sqlj.jdbc.DB2SQLJDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB2url, user, password);
    System.out.println("From DAO, connection obtained ");
    return connection;
}


public boolean addHistory(ThroughputEntry entry) throws Exception {

    try (Connection connection = getConnection()) {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

        return 0 < statement
                .executeUpdate(String
                        .format("INSERT INTO " + table
                                        + "(ID, RETRIEVED, PERIOD_END, ENVIRONMENT, APPNAME, THROUGHPUT)"
                                        + "VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', %s)",
                                entry.getUUID(), entry.getRetrieved(),
                                entry.getPeriodEnd(), entry.getEnvironment(),
                                entry.getName(), entry.getThroughput()));


    }
}
}
```

So my problem is that I'm getting a memory leak on the `Wildfly` AS, and I think the problem could be with my consumer.

So a few questions:

should I be buffering the messages received in my `onMessage()` method on the consumer before inserting them into the DB?

if I'm getting too many messages could this be causing the leak? does the consumer send any sort og `Ack` to the `Wildfly` AS?

I have the consumer running indefinitely with a loop, maybe this is wrong maybe it should sleep, or wait.

I've been 2 days trying to solve this now, any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should close anything needs to be closed. I'm looking at the first few lines and I'm already seeing two streams that are not being closed.

Review your code, anything that implements `AutoCloseable` needs to be properly closed. Use a [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to do that.

IDE's can already give you pointers to possible resource leaks, eg in Eclipse tweak warnings in `Java Compiler>Errors/Warnings`.

---

**Edit**: you edited your question and now a clear leak is visible. In the `parseApplication` method you have the statement `db.getConnection()`. The method creates a connection that you never use **and** you never close it..

Comment: Thank you I'll review my code now and fix anything I may have missed, I assume on the first few lines you're talking about the `InputStream`, could this be causing a leak on my `Wildfly AS`?

Comment: I'm using Intelliej, I assume it has a similar  function?

Comment: @Johntk Anything that implements `AutoCloseable` and that is not closed, has a high chance of causing a leak. There are exceptions, but you should not look for exceptions to that rule. You should identify all uses of classes that implement `AutoCloseable` and strictly close them, all the time. That's the only way to be sure.

Comment: @Johntk I do not use IntelliJ, but I would be surprised if it didn't have similar functionality to spot `AutoCloseable`'s not being closed properly. Look it up in your favorite search engine.

Comment: I understand the logic of making sure to close anything that implements `AutoCloseable` I'll be more aware of this in the future, I'm just struggling to understand how a leak on my `Consumer` could propagate on a different machine AKA the `Wildfly AS`, or can it?

Comment: @Johntk I'm seeing `DBConnection db = DBConnection.createApplication(); db.getConnection();` in your `parseApplication` method. Best review that part as well, I'm not seeing anything being closed.

Comment: I have that connection in a `try-with-resources` in `DBconnection` class, I've modified my code with this class.

Comment: @Johntk It could possibly, if your consumer is using resources from WildFly AS and not releasing them (~closing them). Resource leaks are nine times out of ten because objects weren't properly closed.

Comment: Some of this code was copy and pasted from legacy code I was given, it has a lot of `AutoCloseables` not closed, this could be my problem.

Comment: @Johntk Updated answer, you clearly have a leak regarding the connection you create in the `parseApplication` method

Comment: That was not there when I was testing it, it was lefter over from a clean up I did today, however I have modified my code to remove all possibilities of a leak... I hope. I'm getting a `ConcurrentModificationException` at the moment once I resolve that and run the code to see if the leak is gone I will report back.

Comment: I have solved this by updating to `wildlfly 10 final`, but now my threads are steadily increasing, this was not an issues on `wildlfy 9` looks like another day trying to figure this one out.